# MYSQL get records before particular month and year

Tags: mysql

I want to get latest record before `dd-01-2014`. Just want records on the bases of month and year only.

```
SELECT balance
 FROM `loan_principal_trx` 
 WHERE loan_id=1 AND MONTH(date)<1 AND YEAR(date)<2014
 ORDER BY date DESC 
 LIMIT 0,1
```

I am trying to modify `MONTH(date)<1 AND YEAR(date)<2014` to also get record in `01-01-2013`.
how to only compare month and year.

Thank you

Comment: why you are searching for saperate month and saperate year

Comment: Can you give a sample table and the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm interpreting your question correctly but seems like all you want are records from before `2014-01-01`

```
SELECT balance
FROM `loan_principal_trx` 
WHERE loan_id=1 AND date < '2014-01-01'
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') < DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'),'%M %Y')
```

**(OR)**

```
WHERE YEAR(date) < 2008 
AND MONTH(date) < 01
```